# Trouble connecting with Remminna

Tags: remote, remmina

I have a trouble connecting with remmina desktop to a windows 7 machine.

I can connect using the ip-address, but not with the computername.

If I type in the computername, it gives me a error "could not connect"
When I connect with the IP address, it works OK.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "computername.local" instead of computername? I don't know about windows, but that's how i connect to my Ubuntu boxes on my LAN on VNC, SSH and other services.

Good luck!